# How to detect touch move over a large number of views?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, hover, android-touch-event, touchmove

**My Requirement** : I need to animate a 7*16 LED Display by passing frames through the Android App over BluetoothLE. I have created the design of the display on the app and added empty views with gradient drawable background to them. The colour of these views need to change when my touch moves into them. Adding a touch listener to each view isn't going to help in my case.

**What I have achieved** : I have a large number of views (100+) added programmatically with a tag set to each of them. I have set an OnTouch Event Handler for the parent view in which these views have been added. 
By tracking the absolute coordinates of the touch event (x and y) and comparing with the absolute bounds of a few individual views that I am looping in the touch event handler, I am able to detect hover like touch move (out of bounds to in bounds) over 3-4 views properly.

I have referred the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21903640

**Where I am stuck** : However, when I try to increase the loop size to cover all the added views, the app response slows down and hover detection fails on most of the views. I know this is happening because of heavy computation in the OnTouch Event Handler which I am not supposed to do.

**What I need** : I need an improvement on this solution in terms of performance or an alternative way to go about reaching my goal.

Code Snippet

```
void DrawScreen()
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < 8; column++)
            {
                for (int row = 0; row < 17; row++)
                {
                    relativeLayout.AddView(DrawRect(row, column));
                }
            }
        }

View DrawRect(int row, int column)
        {
            View customView = new View(Context);
            GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
            shape.SetShape(ShapeType.Rectangle);
            shape.SetCornerRadii(new float[] { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 });
            shape.SetColor(Color.ParseColor("#3F0000"));
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            param.LeftMargin = ((column-1) * (width + h_spacing)) + h_spacing;
            param.Width = width;
            param.Height = height;
            param.TopMargin = ((row-1) * (height + v_spacing)) + v_spacing;
            customView.Background = shape;
            customView.LayoutParameters = param;
            customView.Tag = (8 - column).ToString() + "," + (17 - row).ToString();           
            return customView;
        }

private void RelativeLayout_Touch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
        {
            out_of_bounds = true;
            view_in_bound = null;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int row = 1; row < 8; row++)
            {
                for (int column = 1; column < 17; column++)
                {
                    View view = relativeLayout.FindViewWithTag(row.ToString() + "," + column.ToString());

                    if (CheckInterSection(view, e.Event.RawX, e.Event.RawY))
                    {
                        if (out_of_bounds == true)
                        {
                            view_in_bound = view;
                            out_of_bounds = false;
                            Log.Debug("Touch", "Inside");
                            //ToggleViewState(view);                                   
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Log.Debug("Touch", "Still Inside");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (view == view_in_bound)
                        {
                            out_of_bounds = true;
                            view_in_bound = null;
                            Log.Debug("Touch", "Outside");
                        }                                
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

bool CheckInterSection(View view, float rawX, float rawY)
        {
            int[] location = new int[2];
            view.GetLocationOnScreen(location);           
            int x = location[0] - h_spacing/2;
            int y = location[1] - v_spacing/2;
            int width = (view.Width + h_spacing/2);
            int height = (view.Height + v_spacing/2);
            return (!(rawX < x || rawX > (x + width) || rawY < y || rawY > (y + height)));
        }
```

Comment: Why set an OnTouch Event Handler for the parent view in which these views have been added.How are so many views displayed?You can explain detail why do this.What is the specific function you want to achieve?This will be helpful for giving a solution.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT have added my requirement to further clarify my issue. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for updating. If there are a lot of views, and you need to respond to Touch at the same time, the burden on the UI is very large, and eventually the interface will be stuck and the display will not be timely. There is a possible solution, which is to add only a Touch event to the parent view. When the finger slides over multiple child views of the screen, the range and trajectory of the Touch are calculated by the code, which seems to be a solution for processing the algorithm.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Actually, I have managed to implement a formula wherein as soon as a child is touched the neighbouring child views become the range reducing loop size to 9 (3*3). Although, I have noticed only a small improvement. I had also thought of adding trajectory and also a minimum touch move distance to further fine tune performance. However, I have observed that the touch event is triggered only around 40 times a second which is too less to accommodate further optimization as it would result in non-responsive touch. Is that less than normal?

Comment: Not sure the special times.But not understand need to calculate how much times a second. If touch in range of view,then changing color.And only one touch event in Parent View,where it move into, where changing its color.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT For my UI to be responsive, a fast touch move over every view it crosses over should be detected. However, if the touch event is triggered less often, the chances of missing a touch event over a view will be missed. Also, since there are a large number of views, the size of each view is very small, further increasing chances of a missed detection. Also, I know this is possible since I have seen an app (check 'Chemion' on Google Play) capable of handling twice the number of views than mine with no issues. (PS: I have touch handler only on parent, not on the child views)

Comment: Okey, do you have a try with `if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Move)`?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Oh... Should I be considering that since a complete touch event consists of one MotionEventActions.Done, followed by a series of MotionEventActions.Move and finally one MotionEventActions.Up. Or have I misunderstood/missed something?

Comment: Yeah, no miss, you can try with `Move`.  If moving ,it will continuous trigger.It’s best to show you the current results with a video.This will help to better propose optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use trajectory angles to further reduce the loop size but the performance was  never up to my expectations and touch events over views were getting missed regularly.

Then I realized that I was going in the wrong direction and found a much simpler solution. Since my views were being added programmatically and were of same size, I knew the coordinates and bounds of each view in the layout. So I divided the layout into a grid and depending upon the touch coordinates, I was able to identify over which section the touch was on. Below is my solution which has been working perfectly. However, I will wait a while till I mark this as a solution since someone could have a better implementation of my technique or an alternative solution.

```
void DrawScreen()
        {            
            for (int column = 1; column < 17; column++)
            {
                for (int row = 1; row < 8; row++)
                {
                    relativeLayout.AddView(DrawRect(row, column));
                }
            }
        }

View DrawRect(int row, int column)
        {
            View customView = new View(Context);
            if (!CheckBit(row - 1, column - 1))
            {
                customView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.off_rounded_btn);
            }
            else
            {
                customView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.rounded_btn);
            }
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            param.LeftMargin = ((column-1) * (width + h_spacing)) + h_spacing;
            param.Width = width;
            param.Height = height;
            param.TopMargin = ((row-1) * (height + v_spacing)) + v_spacing;
            customView.LayoutParameters = param;
            customView.Tag = row.ToString() + "," + column.ToString();           
            return customView;
        }

void RelativeLayout_Touch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
            {
                view_in_bound = null;
            }
            else
            {
                int row = CheckTouchArea(e.Event.RawX, e.Event.RawY)[0];
                if (row != 0)
                {
                    int column = CheckTouchArea(e.Event.RawX, e.Event.RawY)[1];
                    check_view = GetView(row, column);
                    if (check_view != view_in_bound)
                    {
                        ChangeViewState(check_view, Touch_CheckBit(row - 1, column - 1), row - 1, column - 1);
                        view_in_bound = check_view;
                    }
                }   
            }
        }

int[] CheckTouchArea(float rawX, float rawY)
        {
            int[] tag = new int[2];
            int[] location = new int[2];
            relativeLayout.GetLocationOnScreen(location);
            float x = location[0] + h_padding / 2;
            int y = location[1] + v_padding / 2;
            float width = relativeLayout.Width - h_padding;
            int height = relativeLayout.Height - v_padding;
            if ((!(rawX < x || rawX > (x + width) || rawY < y || rawY > (y + height))))
            {
                int column = (int)Math.Ceiling((rawX - x) * 16 / width);
                int row = (int)(Math.Ceiling((rawY - y) * 7 / height));
                tag[0] = row;
                tag[1] = column;
            }            
            return tag;
        }
```